# Property of Intersection Multiplicity

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Can somebody explain when can one use this property of intersection multiplicities:

For nonzero homogeneous polynomials F,G and H

$$I_P(F,G)=I_P(F,G+FH)$$ provided that $G+FH$ is a homogeneous polynomial.

To be more specific, I am studying on the solution of this problem found on the book Elementary Geometry of Algebraic Curves by Gibson:

Find the points of intersection and its multiplicities of the curves $$F=y^5-x(y^2-xz)^2$$ and $$G=y^4+y^3z-x^2z^2.$$

At one part of the solution it says, $$I_P(F,G)=I_P(F-xG,G)$$ where $$F-xG=y^2(y-2x)(y^2+xz)$$ in factored form. I am suspecting that it was the property above that was used. However, I do not know what was the reason why the property was used.

Comment: What is your question exactly ? Because $I_P(F,G)=I_P(F,G+FH)$ is indeed true under the above hypothesis, and this is the equality used in the solution.

Comment: My question is, in general, when can I use this property.

Comment: @Roland Because it wasn't clear to me what are  the underlying assumptions to apply the property. One observation that I made is that the curve $F$ is of degree 5 as well as $F-xG$. Was the property used because the curve $F-xG$ has a factorization?

Comment: I'm still don't sure about what you're asking. The underlying assumptions seems pretty clear for me : you need $F,G,H$ and $G+FH$ homogeneous. As you said, in the example, this is indeed the case so you can apply the property. In fact, the intersection number is a local property, so that you can compute it in an affine chart containing $P$. In that case, $F,G$ and $H$ are replace by polynomials with only two variables, and there is no hypothesis at all : the equality is always true.

Comment: As to WHY the equality is used, this is indeed for the factorization of $F-xG$. Indeed, there is another useful property of intersection number, namely that $I_P(F,GH)=I_P(F,G)+I_P(F,H)$ (if $F,G$ and $H$ are homogeneous, or without hypothesis in an affine chart). So in your case, you get $I_P(F,G)=2I_P(F,y)+I_P(F,y-2x)+I_P(F,y^2+xz)$. Now, those numbers are much easier to compute directly. Or you can use the first equality again to simplify again.

Comment: Now, it is all clear to me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The point is that the intersection multiplicity can be determined from the ideal $(F, G) < k[x,y,z]$ alone -- in the modern way of thinking, we'd say that $(F, G)$ is the ideal of the scheme-theoretic intersection of $V(F)$ and $V(G)$, which means in essence that it encodes a set of points (the points of intersection) with multiplicities.

Clearly $(F, G)$ and $(F, G - xF)$ are always the same ideal, under no assumptions at all.  $(F, G)$ is the set of elements of the form $p F + q G$, where $p, q \in k[x, y, z]$.  If we have such an element, then

$$p F + q G = (p-qx)F + q(G - xF) \in (F, G- x F)$$

and similarly for the other containment.  This is just linear algebra; in fact, if we have *any* matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}(x,y,z) & a_{12}(x,y,z) \\
a_{21}(x,y,z) & a_{22}(x,y,z) \end{bmatrix}$$

with nonzero determinant then we have

$$(F, G) = (a_{11} F + a_{12} G, a_{21} F + a_{22} G)$$

for the same reason.

So we're free to choose different generators for the same ideal in order to simplify our problem.  Since the methods you're working with to calculate intersection multiplicity assume they're given homogeneous generators, we want also want to do this in such a way that our new choice of generators is also homogeneous.